# How to convert Latitude and Longitude to SPC

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, state-plane

I am working with a set of data that is in Latitude and Longitude. I need to convert this data to State Plane Coordinates. Does anyone know a formula to be able to do this or a Java library that can do this?

I have been looking online have found [this](https://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkweb/) from NOAA but I am needing to implement this in Java for a piece of software and would need something with an API or just a formula.

Comment: What does SPC stand for?

Comment: State plane coordinate

Comment: Look for the Java proj4 port or geotools. If you're doing more than a handful of SPC zones, you'll have to have a table of the parameters or use the [EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org) well-known IDs IF the Java proj4 port supports them. Search here for projection and java to find other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) handles [reprojection](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html) of SRS for you.

You can use code like:

```
boolean lenient = false;
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
CoordinateReferenceSystem target = CRS.decode("EPSG:3649");

MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(crs, target, lenient );
ReferencedEnvelope res = new ReferencedEnvelope(JTS.transform(bbox, transform),target);
```

Looking Up the EPSG code of your state plane is easy at http://epsg.io (for example [EPSG:3649](http://epsg.io/3649))